# Animating tableView slowly when sorting rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableView` which is populated with some `NSMutableArray`.
Later when i sort the array, i want the table view to move slowly each row to its new position, and by slowly i mean about 0.3seconds , so you can see the switch .

I have tried these(with all kinds of animations(top,left,fade,etc) :

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

and its not seems like what i have described here, but some unclear reloading.
I actually want to see row 4 go all the way up to be row 2 ,when its replacing places with the rows in its way up.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Please tag fully, as objective-C is also for OSX. I tagged `ios` and `uitableview`, for this i had to read full question and finally after scrolliing to right I came to know you wanted to **`ios`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the tableview explicitly which row should move where. I use the below code, which works well for me. The "ObjectMap" is my own class which maps objects to numbers in this case. Kind of like an NSDictionary, but using the object pointer to compare.

```
    NSArray *originalList = ...
    ObjectMap *map = [ObjectMap objectMap];
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    for (Waypoint *waypoint in originalList) {
        [map setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index++] forObjectKey:waypoint];
    }

    NSArray *sortedList = ... // sorted version of the originalList

    // do the animations
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [theTableView reloadData];
    }];

    [theTableView beginUpdates];
    index = 0;
    for (Waypoint *waypoint in sortedList) {
        NSNumber *originalIndex = [map objectForKey:waypoint];
        [theTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[originalIndex integerValue] inSection:0]
                             toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index++ inSection:0]];
    }
    [theTableView endUpdates];

    [CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UITableView` Category, and call `reloadDataAnimated:YES` ,this will add fade effect when reloading table data:

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

 @implementation UITableView (Animated)

    - (void)reloadDataAnimated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [self reloadData];

        if (animated)
        {
            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
            [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
            [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
            [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
            [animation setDuration:.3];
            [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"UITableViewReloadDataAnimationKey"];
        }
    }

    @end
```

Comment: he wants animation to occur on cells(UITableViewCells) not on tableView.

Answer (score 0):

use -

`(void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath`

method;
So, if you wanted to move from 4 to 2, first move from 4 to 3 then 3 to 2.It will work.